# Tomcat Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I learn spring MVC, try to create MVC Dynamic Web project, which needs to connect tomcat server. I don't know for what reason I'm getting the following error (I copy hereunder last lines)

```
 Jun 13, 2021 3:22:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
 INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
 Jun 13, 2021 3:22:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
 INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
 Jun 13, 2021 3:22:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
 INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
 WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
 WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase 
 (file:/B:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%209.0/lib/catalina.jar) to 
 field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
 WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of 
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
 WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access 
 operations
 WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

I found one more post related to this error:

```
 To silence these warnings, you will need the following options in your startup script:

 --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
 --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
 --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Unfortunately I don't what is startup script & how to find it on windows.

grateful if someone could help me to get the rid of this error.

Comment: Java 1.8 & Tomcat 9.0.46

Comment: Add details as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: How do you start (and stop) the Tomcat instance?